# Not able to auto fill to the last row

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I'm working on a dynamic range which always refreshes itself with the new data.

The problem is that I'm unable to autofill, and also I'm using offset so its giving me problem on how to use the last row.

Here is the code:

```
WB3.Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
lstRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range (("D2:D") & lstRow)
Range(("O2:O") & lstRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($B2821,Sheet2!A1:BX6149,65,0)"
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this to put the `VLOOKUP` formula to the last row?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: First of all you don't need that extra brackets in `Range("D2:D" & lstRow)`. The second is you didn't ask any question. What do you expect your code to do? What does your code actually? Please read [ask] and ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fully qualify your references to make sure that all the `Range` and `Rows` apply to `WB3.Worksheets("sheet1")`. Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim lstRow As Long
    With WB3.Worksheets("sheet1")
        lstRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("O2:O" & lstRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($B2821,Sheet2!$A$1:$BX$6149,65,0)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Robin, you forgot to lock the rows index inside the `VLookup`, it needs to be `"=VLOOKUP($B2821,Sheet2!A$1:BX$6149,65,0)"`